# win-rt live sdk: how to connect with access token

Tags: windows-runtime

In win-rt app, I want to auto connect to Windows Live with access token after the first time user logged in, so that next time users open the app they do not need to login again. just use Live SDK and do not call its REST API in my code, is this doable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PhotoSky - SkyDrive Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141) from Windows 8 sample apps.

Comment: Hi Mayank, yes, i have tried it. It only saves LiveConnectSession to a variable in App.xaml.cs, but if user restart his PC, he has to login again. Since we can get access token after user is connected, can we connect to Live SDK again using access token so that user doesn't need to login again?